# How to modify $uri to avoid HTTP-Splitting vulnerability

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

How can I modify below block to overcome HTTP-Splitting vulnerability. There is an official recommendation to instead use $uri_request but unfortunately that doesn't work for below code.

```
location /store {
 if ($arg_page) {
        return 301 $uri;
    }
  try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of using the `$request_uri` variable is that unsafe characters should already be percent-encoded. The `$uri` variable is fully decoded which increases the risk of vulnerability when used in a `return` statement.

The `$uri` variable has also had the argument list removed, which seems to be why you are using it here - to strip the argument list (particularly `?page=` argument) from the URL.

The solution might be to use `rewrite` instead of `return`. The [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) already has the ability to remove the argument list, will percent-encode the response, and seems to refuse to process requests containing questionable content.

For example:

```
location /store {
    if ($arg_page) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1? permanent;
    }
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
```